# How to set a global variable for all virtual users during gatling simulation?

Tags: gatling

In my simulation users are simply sending requests in a loop. Each request contains a custom header and its value is read from a variable.
However, I would like to change the value of the variable during simulation so that all virtual users (including active) start sending a new value in the custom header from this point.

Here's what I've tried but with no luck:

```
class MySimulation extends Simulation {
  
  var GLOBAL_LIMIT = "49"

  def myRequest: HttpRequestBuilder =
    http("My request")
      .get("/")
      .header("LIMIT", GLOBAL_LIMIT)
      .check(status.is(200))

  def myScenario: ScenarioBuilder =
    scenario("Poll")
      .forever(
        pace(1.second)
          .exec(myRequest)
      )

  def changeLimit(limit: String): ScenarioBuilder =
    scenario("Change limit")
      .exec(session => {
        GLOBAL_LIMIT = limit
        session
      })

  setUp(
    myScenario.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(1) during 30.seconds
    ),
    changeLimit("59").inject(
      nothingFor(10.seconds),
      atOnceUsers(1)
    )
  ).protocols(http.baseUrl("http://localhost:8081"))
}
```

I've also tried to store the value with `scala.util.Properties.setProp()` and than read it with `scala.util.Properties.propOrElse()` but that doesn't work either. All requests have the custom header set to initial value of `"49"`.

Is there a way to set (and then change) global variables for simulation, something like session but common for all virtual users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you're writing `.header("LIMIT", GLOBAL_LIMIT)`, you're passing a **value** as the `header` method's second parameter, and this value is evaluated once **when the simulation is loaded**. At this point in time, `GLOBAL_LIMIT` is still null as it will only be populated later when the simulation will be running.

Instead, you must pass a **function** that will be **evaluated every time** a virtual user tries to generate this request:

```scala
.header("LIMIT", session => GLOBAL_LIMIT)
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!